# How to print N number of primes in Visual Basic

Tags: vb.net-2010

I have this visual basic code to receive user input and print out that many primes. For instance if a user inputs 5, the output should be: 1, 3, 5, 7, 11. Here is my code:

```
        Dim i, n, input, currentPrime As Integer
        Dim Wrap As String = Chr(10) & Chr(13)
        ' input = TextBox2.Text
        currentPrime = 0
        txtOutput.Text = "Prime Numbers are : " & Wrap
        'Do Until (currentPrime <= input)
        For i = 0 To 500
            For j = 2 To Fix(i / 2) + 1
                If i Mod j = 0 Then
                    n = 1
                End If
            Next
            If n = 1 Then
                n = 0
            Else
                txtOutput.Text = txtOutput.Text & Wrap & i & " is a prime number " & Wrap

            End If
        Next
        currentPrime += 1
        'Loop
    End If
```

Do notice that the input and my Do loop is commented out. This is done because if I try to use this method nothing will print out and my program will lock up. However if I comment it out the program will print the prime numbers too 499.

Does anyone know a way I can make this loop work? Any help is appreciated as I am a beginner in Visual Basic.

Comment: Incidentally, you should use [Option Strict On](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/zcd4xwzs.aspx). You see where you have `input = TextBox2.Text`? That means that you are trying to put a String into an Integer. Without Option Strict On, VB will have a go at converting the string to an integer: usually it will get it right, but it would be horrible to try and debug it when it doesn't. You can use functions like [Integer.Parse](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/b3h1hf19%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) to explicitly do the conversion in a defined way.

Comment: the j for loop will have a very poor performance (also checking division till the Square root of i should be enough, no need to to go as far as the half of the nr). I would suggest simply suggest to define the upperlimit just above the j for loop, as that would not prompt a new calculation on each iteration

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a function to determine if a number is a prime (it simply helps if you need the function at a later time)

```
Function IsPrime(number As Integer) As Boolean
    If number <= 2 Then
        Return False
    End If
    Dim upperLimit As Integer = number ^ 0.5
    For i As Integer = 2 To upperLimit
        If number Mod i = 0 Then
            Return False
        End If
    Next
    Return True
End Function
```

loop your range of nr's and each time one is found, add primesFound

```
Sub Main()
    Dim totalItems As Integer = 100
    Dim primesFound As Integer = 0
    Dim currentNumber As Integer = 3


    While primesFound < totalItems
        If IsPrime(currentNumber) Then
            Console.WriteLine("{0} is a prime number", currentNumber)
            primesFound = primesFound + 1
        End If
        currentNumber = currentNumber + 2
    End While
    Console.WriteLine("Done, press any key to exit!")
    Console.GetKey()
End Sub
```

btw, in my opinion, 1 & 2 is not a prime nr ;), and checking for prime nr's should only start from the nr 3

Comment: 1 is not a prime number, but if you unilaterally decide that 2 is not a prime number, then 4, 8, 16... are not prime numbers either.

Comment: If you modify your posted code so that it includes 2 as a prime number, you will avoid that answer getting downvoted ;) Also, you probably want `Console.GetKey()` to go along with "Press *any* key".

Answer (score 1):

Your logic is backwards

```
do until (currentprime <= input)
```

If your input is 5, then currentprime starts at 0, and `0 <= 5` is true, killing the loop right then and there.

```
do until (currentprime >= input)
```

is what you want. "do this stuff until you've found more primes than the user wanted".

Plus, the internal primality testing could use some help:

```
            If i Mod j = 0 Then
                n = 1
            End If
```

This will detect if/when you find a divisor of the number (e.g. the number isn't prime), but then you simply keep on testing. You've already proven the number is composite, so there's no point in further testing. You're not GlaDOS - you can given up at that point and move on to the next candidate number.

Answer (score 1):

Try like this:

```
Dim i, n, input As Integer
Dim Wrap As String = Chr(10) & Chr(13)
input = TextBox2.Text
txtOutput.Text = "Prime Numbers are : "

For i = 0 To input
    For j = 2 To Fix(i / 2) + 1
        If i Mod j = 0 Then
            n = 1
        End If
    Next

    If n = 1 Then
        n = 0
    Else
        txtOutput.Text = txtOutput.Text & " " & i & " is a prime number." & Wrap
    End If
Next
```

I haven't debuged the code. But I think its correct now.

Answer (score 1):

This is the code you need. I too took a long time to figure out the logic and making it complex bit by bit but just did a bit of rough page work. Hope this Helps!

P.S I too was looking for the program on internet and did not find it :)
The Code:

```
    Private Sub Button1_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    Dim i, j, k, a As Integer
    k = InputBox("Enter the Number of First Prime Numbers")
    For a = 1 To k
        j = Val(TextBox1.Text)
        j = j + 1
        For i = 2 To j - 1
            If j Mod i = 0 Then
                j = j + 1
            Else
            End If
        Next
        TextBox1.Text = j
        TextBox2.Text = TextBox2.Text & "  " & j
    Next
End Sub
```

End Class

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried:

```
For i = CurrentPrime To Input
```

?

Your do loop should probably been a "Do While" instead of "Do Until", but if your program would lock up/crash I wonder if your TextBox2.Text is giving a non-numeric value.  Is this program kicked off by a button-press?